# Perforce restore client workspace after hard disk crash

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

My hard disk crashed and i lost all the files in the shadow (client workspace). Now after reinstalling perforce I can see my workspace from the GUI (all the root-view mappings).

Any pointers on how to get all my client workspace files back.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  If that disc is no longer functional, then the files that were on it are lost.  Workspace *definitions* are stored on the server, but the files they contain are not.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can I not use any variation of p4 sync command, to download all these files back. I am confused because the following page [link](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/sync.html) describes p4 sync command as : Brings the client workspace into sync with the depot by **copying files matching its file pattern arguments from the depot to the client workspace**.  I am a newbie to using perforce so i am scared to try out p4 sync. Any comformation would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can resync from the depot, however you won't be able to recover any local changes that you had on your client if that HDD is no longer functional. There is no magical back-up-my-work-in-case-of-hdd-failure feature in any source control system.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for your reply. Can u please tell me the exact command for resyncing.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were looking to recover the files you were working on (which are now gone).  If you just want to retrieve files that are in version control the command is `p4 sync \\depot\path\...`